# How can I remove this white space from a table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table I have simplified for this question while preserving the problem.
It is a single row with three cells. The middle one contains an image and the first and last ones fill the remaining space and are textually supposed to be empty.
The height of the first and last cell adapts to that of the central (image) one as it is the highest, which does work -
but they become a tad bigger than they should visually creating a hole beneath the central cell.

HTML:

```
<article class="content" id="pc">
    <table id="contentTable">
    <tr>
    <td class="pad" id="padL"></td>
    <td id="cc">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/b9dc51057ece7352d07d40f4c59f0c65/tumblr_nb0xmfghdm1tin2h1o1_500.jpg" width="250"/>
   </a>
             </td>
     <td class="pad" id="padR"></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </article>
```

CSS:

```
 #contentTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 700px;
 }

 #cc {
    width: 500px;
 }

 .pad {
     background-color: gray;
     vertical-align: middle;
 }

 #padR {
     border-top-right-radius: 2em;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
 }

 #padL {
     border-top-left-radius: 2em;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
 }
```

Here is a screen shot of the problem with the space highlighted in blue
[image]
And a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bgnlc) if it helps.

Why does it occur and how can I remove it?

Comment: You can achieve the same effect without using a table: http://jsfiddle.net/d4mg4360/

Comment: @rhino thank you! - would be great but I need that background to be a link (and to appear on hover) which I don't think I can do with a background per se. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your image is `inline`, it obeys rules of baseline and has space at the bottom.

I had success by setting:

```css
img {
    display:block;
}
```

To get rid of other table spacing (not showing in your screen-shot), I suggest adding:

```css
#contentTable {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    ...
}

#contentTable tr td{
    padding:0;
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdpGb)

### EDIT

Per your comment, here's an example using an embedded YouTube video (iframe). Iframes default to `display:inline` ([replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)), too.

```css
iframe { display:block; }
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKHzr)

Comment: Thanks it does it but I think I will need to replace the Img with a video or text at some point, and then it occurs again, what would be a universal solution for any td content?

Comment: With what did you replace the image? If it's already block content, you don't need to set `display:block`.

Comment: +1 for proper table spacing & padding :) MDN has some good further info regarding the above solution https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Comment: Ok, I tried setting a div instead and things like that but it didn't work that way so replacing the img with other selectors of that type works

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the cell containing the picture.

```
    <td class="pad" id="cc">
```